# How to display an image like popup from View

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, fileresult

I created an QR code image using **MessagingToolkit.QRCode.dll** in a button click. I have saved the image in the disk. How to display the image separately from view as pop up ??
**Here is my controller code :**

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult GenerateQR(string Command, FormCollection collection)
    {
    // qr code logic //
       QRCodeEncoder encoder = new QRCodeEncoder();
       Bitmap img = encoder.Encode(qrcode);
       img.Save(@"D:\\Capture.png", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    // Checking the image present in the filepath and displaying the image.
       string filePath = @"D:\\Capture.png";
       if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
          return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('The Image is not available.');</script>");
       else
          return new FilePathResult(filePath, "image/png");
    }
```

Here the image is displayed in view completely. How to display the image as separate popup from the view.

Comment: using jquery popup and ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of bringing like a popup, I got the image directly from using the below code.

```
QRCodeEncoder encoder = new QRCodeEncoder();
Bitmap img = encoder.Encode(qrcode);
string path = Server.MapPath(@"/Images/QRCode.jpg");        
img.Save(path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);        
return base.File(path,"image/jpeg","QRCode.jpg");
```